# Firebase Auth, acquiring textfield value from different class

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase email authentication in my app, I have 2 different view controllers for the sign up process, first view controller asks for the email for firebase and the second view controller asks for the password. How can I set it up for the firebase code?

```
if let phoneEmail = phoneEmailTextField.text, let createdpassword = createdPasswordTextField {

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: phoneEmail, password: createdpassword, completion: { (user, error) in
```

I have the textfield "phoneEmailTextField" in the first view controller (class 1) and the textfield "createdPasswordTextField" in the second view controller(class 2). How can I link the textfield "createdPasswordTextField" from the second view controller (class 2) back to the first view controller (class 1) in order to execute the Firebase function?

Answer (score 0):

Use segue for passing mail textfield's data from first view controller to the second.Shortly,search how segue,navigation controller pushing works.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that;

```
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
 if let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController {
secondViewController.emailTextFieldString = emailTextField.text! 
           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
                }
```